# dynamic selectInput's where subsequent selectInput's are dependant on previous selections

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to create a Shiny page that includes dynamic inputs based on the results of a query. I want the inputs choices to be dependent on the previous `selectInput()` selection. The query results are returned as a series of data.tables held in a `reactiveValue()` and are structured as follows :

```
V1    V2    V3    V4          V5    key_index
along with  this  development comes 45473
```

the first `selectInput()` choices option is just a list of the pasted columns V1:V5 of the first data.table. I am trying to make it so that the next and subsequent `selectInputs()` are comprised of the V1:V5 of its associated table where V1 of that table is the same as V5 of the previous. Using the sample data the choices of the second `selectInput()` would then be made up of only the ngrams of data.table 2 that begin with 'comes'. This is how I've been trying to create the first input in such a way that it will return a value i can use to set the second input, but I cant even get past the first input in the series. Is there a better way of doing this?

```
trythis <- reactive({
  tmpthis <- unlist(lapply(1:nrow(ngra1), function(n) ngra1[n,5]))
  return(tmpthis)
})
trythat <- reactive({
  tmpthat <- unlist(lapply(1:nrow(ngra1), function(m) paste0(ngra1[m,1:5],collapse=" ")))
  return(tmpthat)
})
output$oneapage <- renderUI({
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fluidRow(
        print(trythat()),
        print(trythis()),
        thing <- for(j in 1:length(trythat())){paste("'",trythat()[[j]],"' = '",trythis()[[j]],"'")},
        selectInput("tester","test",choices = c(thing[1:length(thing)]))
    )
),
```

Comment: Please consider accepting your own answer (by clicking on check mark). This will mark this post as closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code I finally settled on. The bit that allowed me to finally pull it all together was using `input[[]]` to access the contents of an input variable

```
output$ngram_res_panel <- renderUI({
  tagList(
    fluidRow(
      column(selectInput("box1",NULL,choices = c("choose",ngram$results[[1]]$th),selected = input$box1,selectize=FALSE),width=5
      )
    ),       
      lapply(2:length(ngram$results), function(i) {
        tagList(
          fluidRow(
            column(selectInput(inputId = paste0("box", i), label = NULL,
                  choices = c("choose",ngram$results[[i]]$th[which(ngram$results[[i]]$V1 == ngram$results[[i-1]]$last[
                      which(input[[paste0("box", i-1)]] == ngram$results[[i-1]]$th)
                      ])
                    ]),selected = input[[paste0("box", i)]],selectize=FALSE 
                  ),width = 5)
          )
        )
     })
   )
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

I made up the following data frame that's similar in structure to yours. It's a 3-column data.frame of letters:

```
df <- data.frame( V1 = letters[1:10],
                  V2 = letters[2:11],
                  V3 = letters[3:12] )

  V1 V2 V3
1  a  b  c
2  b  c  d
3  c  d  e
...
```

I make a list of the `choice1` options:

```
C1.options <- with(df, paste(V1,V2,V3))
[1] "a b c" "b c d" "c d e" ...
```

You want the user to choose an entry among `C1.options`, *then* subset `df` by `df$V1 == choice1$V3` (let's call this `C2.options`), *then* let the user choose an entry among `C2.options`.

Here's the code block to do that:

```
ui <- fluidPage( 
          selectInput("choice1", "First Choice", C1.options, selected=NULL),
          htmlOutput("plot1")    # render dynamic selectInput in server
      )

server <- function(input,output){
              data <- reactive({ Str <- unlist(strsplit(input$choice1," "))
                                 Str <- Str[length(Str)]   # Grab last character in option 1
                                 Filt <- df %>% filter(V1 == Str)   # Filter by condition
                                 C2.options <- with(Filt, paste(V1,V2,V3))
                                 return(C2.options) })
              output$plot1 <- renderUI({ selectInput("choice2", "Second Choice", data(), selected=NULL)   })
           }

shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```